# Horizontal scrolling toolbar implementation

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, android-webview

I am trying to add a horizontal toolbar at he top of my application (uses android webview and jquery mobile) that contains a bunch of buttons (too many to fit across the screen in a single line).

The problem that I am facing is that instead of hiding the extra buttons, they wrap around to the next line. What I would like is for them to hide and be accessible by scrolling them horizontally just like a native ListView would allow me to do.

I have tried to use a ListView to put the buttons in, and pass the button presses to the javascript code by doing loadUrl(), but this causes other issues and is not usable in my case (it automatically hides the soft keyboard).

I have tried the following code (along with this code wrapped in a jquery mobile toolbar):

```
<ul data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">                    
                <li><a href="" data-role="button" id="boldButton" data-inline="true">B</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="italicButton" data-inline="true">I</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="underlineButton" data-inline="true">U</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="strikethroughButton" data-inline="true">S</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="orderedListButton" data-inline="true">ol</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="unorderedListButton" data-inline="true">ul</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="indentButton" data-inline="true">in</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="outdentButton" data-inline="true">out</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="subscriptButton" data-inline="true">sub</a></li>
<li><a href="" data-role="button" id="superscriptButton" data-inline="true">sup</a></li></ul>
```

But this just wraps around to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ul in a div, and set the div's width property to a large value, enough to accomodate all the buttons.  Then set the overflow property to auto, and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's a start (they are all on the same line), but the issue now is that the whole content scrolls. I would like to just be able to scroll the toolbar without scrolling the entire view.

Comment: @NickLH The problem with what you're trying to do is based in browser support. Scrollable content areas are not well supported by mobile browsers. For a cross-browser implementation I suggest using a JS library that is meant to deal with this, like iScroll 4.

Comment: Did you close off the div after closing the ul?  (</ul></div>)  That should prevent anything below that list from being included in the scrolled region.

Comment: Yeah, I tried closing the div, thanks for the effort. But Jasper's answer worked great. Too bad it's a comment and I can't accept...